# Stateful version of map (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I have just learned about creating higher-order functions and I want to make a map function that is able to change a function that applies to tuples to have that function apply to a list of that type. (Just like the map function.)
I am trying to create it in such a way that it has this signature:

```
statefulMap :: ((a,state) -> (b,state)) -> (([a],state) -> ([b],state))
```

I want to be able to use this function to create a series of full adders, but how do I create this function in the first place?

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? From what I can see it takes a function as an argument and returns another function. I'm having a difficult time understanding how this is like `map` which has the type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Note that `map` takes **two** parameters.

Comment: You can use `mapM` with a state monad for instance.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `statefulMap :: ((a, state) -> (b, state)) -> ([a], state) -> ([b], state)`? Note that the extra set of parentheses in your question makes a lot of difference in the type of the function.

Comment: Maybe you should look at `mapAccumL` and variants.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: no, here the parenthesis are redundant, the two are equal, since the `->` operator works *right-to-left*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh...that's right.../facepalm

Comment: @Code-Apprentice in the case of `map`, you can also apply `map` on a function to change the function from type `(a -> b)` to `([a] -> [b])` which you can then later apply to the second argument. That is what I'm trying to accomplish here, but now while having a state (the _carry_) being passed between the items in the list `[a]` (as with full-adders). 
You could also view the function I am looking for as type:
`((a,state) -> (b,state)) -> ([a],state) -> ([b],state)`
Which already looks a lot more like `map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This actually already exists: we can use a [*state monad*](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) and use the *monadic* version of `map`: `mapM`.

For instance we can write a function for a full adder. Here I think with *state* you mean the carry that the previous full adder has generated.

So we can make a *full adder* as:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

fa :: (Bool, Bool) -> State Bool Bool
fa (a, b) = do
   ci <- get
   let d = a /= b
   put ((ci && d) || (a && b))
   return (ci /= d)
```

The type means that we make a function that alters state. The first `Bool` specifies the type of the state itself (here a boolean, the carry that is `True` or `False`), the second `Bool` specifies what we "return" (here a `True` or `False` as output for the specific full adder).

Now we can make a *stateful* map, with `mapM`:

```
fullAdders :: [(Bool, Bool)] -> State Bool [Bool]
fullAdders = mapM fa
```

This thus takes a list of 2-tuples (the inputs for every full adder), and produces a `State Bool [Bool]`, so the state is still a `Bool`, but the result now is a list of booleans `[Bool]`: a list that contains the output for every full adder.

We can now call it with `fullAdders [(True, True), (True, False), (False, False), (True, True)]` but this will *not* give us a list of booleans, but a `State Bool [Bool]`. We can the "*run*" the state monad by specifying the initial state. We can do this by using `runState :: State a b -> a -> (a, b)`, so we can call it with:

```
runState (fullAdders [(True, True), (True, False), (False, False), (True, True)]) False
```

this produces:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.State.Lazy> runState (fullAdders [(True, True), (True, False), (False, False), (True, True)]) False
([False,False,True,False],True)
```

so a 2-tuple with as first item the result, and as second item the new state (here `True`, since the carry output of the last full adder will be `True`).

Comment: Wow, thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!
My own answer (that just answered the first part of my question was this:
`mapr f (x,state) = (map fst (map f (zip x (replicate (length x) state))), state)` Which looks a lot more messy that yours.